# Web Deploy re-uploads files that don't require it

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Whenever either myself or someone else in my team publishes a website via web deploy to our server, it obviously copies over any newer dll files, cshtml files, css files etc.

However if a different user then does a publish, images, pdf files etc all get re-uploaded, even though it's not required (ie they haven't changed).

Initially I thought this was because we were all using different usernames to publish, however this isn't the problem. Has anyone come across a solution for this? It's quite frustration especially when you're publishing a site that has a lot of static content.

Comment: Check out deployment settings for your profile. I had the same issue and there was a checkbox that was checked (I unchecked it and problem solved.) I can't remember any more than that cause I've been using Linux lately.

Comment: only option i see under 'file publish options' is 'remove additional files at destination', which isn't what i want..

Comment: Oh. Damn. What files are being re-uploaded? Are they auto-generated files, or are they files that you have created yourself?

Comment: Nah files that we've created ourselves. PDFs, JPGs, etc.. static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this isn't technically an 'answer', this isn't an issue for us now using VSTS and CI/CD. We don't see files being replaced, it just works.